# How does belt fit around roller

Tags: technology

I dissembled a printer/scanner for parts.

This is a belt and roller and I think it was used for the scanner.

I can not figure out how the belt fits on the roller?

The belt is a continuous piece and the pin for the roller will not come out unless it is forced out.

Can someone solved the mystery of how to mount the belt?

[image]

Comment: The image of the roller is unclear. However, does the roller rest against the *outside* of the belt??

Comment: I agree with @DrMoishePippik -- could this roller just be used to push against the outside of the belt, to add tension? [Here's an image.](https://www.ibtinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/v-belt-force-deflection-e1517851329269.png) That would explain why you can't loop the belt through or around the roller.

Answer (score 2):

The belt doesn’t feed around the roller. That roller is used as a tensioner, so the roller is entirely inside the belt with the roller pushing the belt outwards to keep it tight.